# Asp.net Web from Dynamic Controls Based on Dynamic controls

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls, webforms

I'm using a wizard control, step 1 has a list box with a list box containing entries 1-10. Step 2 then dynamically build and displays 1 list box per entry. Each list box in step 2 contains 5 entries each. I have one more step that needs to read the list boxes from step 2 and get their values to display 3 radio buttons per choosen entry from step 2.

Currently I have 3 methods that I run populateStep1() populateStep2() populateStep3(). I run each in Page_Load.

```
void page_load()
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      populateStep1();
    }

    populateStep2();
    populateStep3();
}
```

my problem is that step 3 never works the first time around. It works the second time but not the first. I believe this is because the controls in step 2 have not yet had the viewstate applied so there is nothing chosen.

Anyone want sketch out/point me to a pattern to handle working with dynamic controls that are dependent on other dynamic controls?

Comment: I never did get this to work like I wanted. I was able to do it by keeping an object with all the information in the session as a kind of temp data store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with Dynamically added controls then you really need to add them during the Initialization pase of the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) as this will ensure View State is hydrated properly.

Since View State is hydrated before Page_Load, you are adding things too late.

Move your logic into the `Page_Init` method and you should be golden.

```
void Page_Init()
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      populateStep1();
    }

    populateStep2();
    populateStep3();
}
```